# Get only positive answers in a subtraction question python

Tags: python

I'm making a math game, i want my subtraction answers to only have positive integers, how do i do that? I don't want questions like 6-10 but questions like 10-6.

this is the code i tried to make, but it doesn't work. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import random

x=random.randint(1,10)
y=random.randint(1,10)

def q():
    global x,y
    que=int(input("what is {}-{}?".format(x,y)))
    if y>x:
        q()
    else:
        pass

q()
```

Comment: you do not need a `global` keyword unless you the changing the original value of `x` and `y` variables inside your function `q`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) functions:

```
def q():
    greater, smaller = max(x, y), min(x, y)
    que = int(input("what is {}-{}?".format(greater, smaller)))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
def q(x, y):
    if y > x:
        return q(y, x)
    return int(input("what is {}-{}?".format(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the numbers as a tuple first:

```
x, y = sorted((random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
import random

bigger = random.randint(1, 10)
lower = random.randit(1, bigger)

def q(bigger, lower):

    que = int(input(f'What is {bigger} - {lower}?'))
    return que
```

Comment: You might want `bigger = random.randint(2, 10)`, and then `lower = random.randint(1, bigger - 1)`.  The question says *positive*, not *non-negative*. So they can't be the same.

Comment: If `0` is not desired for answer, definetly.

Comment: I'd think this might greatly bias the pick towards smaller numbers, but I'm no statistician…

Comment: Why do you think that @deceze?

Comment: If one random pick averages out to picking 5, then picking two entirely random numbers from 0-10 has a decent chance that one of the two is >5. However, in your approach the average first pick will pick 5 and the second is always lower than that.

Comment: Proof: https://repl.it/repls/OfficialWatchfulVaporware

Comment: Nice prove @deceze, here is another one: What are the chances of getting 0 as a result? On the first method, 1/10*1/10 = 1/100. Whith my code 1/10 * 1/x where x is the first number extracted. Thus, getting P(0) by 1-1 have 1/10 chances, by 2-2 1/20 and so on, making my code biased towards 0. Good point on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use abs() function

```
#random floating number
floating = -1.33
print('Absolute value of -1.33 is:', abs(floating)) # 1.33
```